# Distribute dropdown to column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a column with this type as dropdown: SOPO, NOOS, SOPO&NOOS.
I want to write a code that distributes this column to 2 other columns(with title SOPO and NOOS):

if the dropdown SOPO is selected then in the column SOPO write yes.
if the dropdown NOOS is selected then in the column NOOS write yes
if the dropdown SOPO&NOOS is selected then in the column SOPO and NOOS write yes.

I have written this code but do not get correct result:

```
If .Cells(lngZ_src, dt_col("NOOS/SOPO")).Value = "NOOS" Then
    ws.Cells(lngZ_dest, dt_col_exp("NOOS [NOS]")).Value = "NOOS"
ElseIf .Cells(lngZ_src, dt_col("NOOS/SOPO")).Value = "SOPO" Then
        ws.Cells(lngZ_dest, dt_col_exp("SOPO[Sonderposten/Remainders]")).Value = "SOPO"
ElseIf .Cells(lngZ_src, dt_col("NOOS/SOPO")).Value = "NOOS&SOPO" Then
        ws.Cells(lngZ_dest, dt_col_exp("SOPO[Sonderposten/Remainders]")).Value = "SOPO"
        ws.Cells(lngZ_dest, dt_col_exp("NOOS [NOS]")).Value = "NOOS"
End If
```

for more Information: dt_col is the dictionary for the heading title in this Excel file (Excel1):
[Excel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfCla.jpg)

in this file(Above) in the DropDown-sheet all relevant dropdowns defined:

[DropDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofH5a.jpg)

and dt_col_exp is the dictionary for the heading title in this Excel file:
[Excel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY57q.jpg)

Note: both Excel files are linked and among so many codes the first Excel file is exported to the second one.

Comment: Please, show us all (relevant) code. What  do `dt_col` and `dt_col_exp` mean? At least a sheet a picture of the respective sheet. And what `DropDown` are you talking about? Is it a Form `DropoDown` object, a list validated cell? Anyhow, where does the value of the respective entity appear in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried that corrected my request.